# How compare only date with nhibernate and criteria

Tags: nhibernate, compare, criteria, date

im trying to compare two dates like this

```
ICriteria criteria = base.DataStore.TransactionScope.NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria<CcCorte>();
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Ge("Start", init.Date));
```

But im just need to compare the dates without the time, i can take only date for server variable but dont know how to do it with the other.

Any ideas?

Comment: which version of nhibernate are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following functions are available in HQL, maybe you could use them:

second(...), minute(...), hour(...), day(...), month(...), year(...)

So yea write your query using hql.

and if you think thats not helpful you can always write sql query and use sql servers DateTime functions like DateDiff etc and achieve the same...

Hope that helps.